# Вставить стили внутрь стороннего iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, iframe

У меня есть `iFrame`, который вставляет видео с Facebook'а. Мне необходимо поправить внутренность `iFrame` с помощью стилей. Есть ли какой-то метод как можно подключить стили к внутреннему содержимому  `iFrame`?

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/asdbiketorrese/videos/d41d8cd9/334096281690153/&amp;show_text=0&amp;width=410&amp;height=238" width="410" height="238" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Попробуйте применить стили, подключенные к основному документу, выбирая селектор как дочерний элемент iframe: `iframe .controls` или `iframe ul li`

Comment: Такое было бы возможно, только если бы Facebook [средствами CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) открыл доступ скриптам с вашего домена. Тогда можно было бы добавить блок <style></style> в DOM страницы, открытой во фрейме. См. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: Скидываю ссылку на сайт должно помочь: https://only-to-top.ru/blog/coding/2019-10-03-css-to-iframe.html